# MYSQL Query to count the number of schemas present in mysql server

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql, mysql-workbench

say if the connection is **localhost** which contains 

*information_schema
mysql
performance_schema
test
test_database*

Query to retrieve the count of schemas 
count(schema)

---------------------- 
5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
select count(*) from information_schema.SCHEMATA where schema_name not in
('mysql','information_schema');
```

If you want All database

Then Use

```
select count(*) from information_schema.SCHEMATA where schema_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(SCHEMA_NAME) FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA
```